# Tech employers prefer broad and deep theoretical knowledge? Or do they just want someone with 5 years experience in the latest buzzwords?

Tags: language-agnostic

Using myself as a case study, I I'm quite fluent in many languages across the entire paradigm spectrum (functional, reactive, assembly, OO, you name it). And yet the majority of my actual "industry experience" hasbeen with .net, c# visuall studio etc.

Now, when I look at job adverts, often they look like

> Must have 5 years experience using JQuery, angular, reactJS, microsoft azure etc

I honestly to this day have no idea what these things are, but they sound like buzzwords, and i dont see why it matters that someone has jquery on their CV if they can't actually code very well otherwise.*surely* it's better to hire someone with deep theoretical knowledge, rather than someone who just happens to have a bit of experience with the latest library or framework, but doesn't have much comp sci smarts otherwise?

I know that I am highly and uniquely skilled, and Im fairly confident i could be of use to any tech company, despite the fact that i have no idea what most of the buzzwords on their "must have" list even refer to. If the job requires jquery, i have no clue what that is but you can bet your ass i'll pick it up pretty quick.

The question: isnt it a bit short sighted to require "5 years experience with latest buzzword/library/framework" rather than something more important like "fluent in -list of languages-, experience with -imperative, declarative, object oriented, etc-"? Wouldn't a tech hire who is flexible and able to adapt to any language, paradigm, framework or library be more valuable than someone who knows the latest buzzword but can only do basic code in one paradigm?

Comment: You are kind of right, but the employer is obviously looking for a Web developer, and you are obviously not a Web developer.  Sure you can learn, but it'll be a while before you're in sync with languages, practices, and patterns of the community.  Web developers are not that hard to come by, so the employer would prefer to get one that's ready to go.  That doesn't mean you can't give them a good reason to hire you... if it's a job you really want.  You should find out what Web developers actually do first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s a complaint about job requirements, not a programming question as defined in the Help Center.